# JFactory::getUser($id) not working

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to use JFactory::getUser() to get the name and username of a certain user but it returns error!

For example when I write this:

```
echo JFactory::getUser(645)->name;
```

it returns this error:

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\libraries\joomla\user\user.php on line 888

but it works fine when I enter my own id there, and returns my name!

More info:

I use this function in a field type file, and I already used that in another field type file in the same site and in the same way **without any problem**! The difference between these is that: I'm using this in a custom component, but that was used in the com_categories component.

Comment: Do you get this error consistently?  Are you verifying if a user is logged or what is returned from JFactory::getUser($id) is a valid JUser object?

Answer (score 1):

I thing you should first instantiate a user object.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser(646);
```

and then if it is not null (i.e. he/she exists)

do an

```
echo $user->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

pcrikos is right you have to create an instance of the User object first. Once you have done that you call can then object property in an echo statement. Also note that passing no integer (numerical value) to the method will leverage the current user session as the user state and that user id will be used.

```
//This will instance the user object of the current user state
$user = JFactory::getUser();

//This will instance the user object for a given user defined by passed id aregument
 $user = JFactory::getUser(1);
```

Once you have that object instanced you can call any of the method properties to get the data you seek.

```
echo $user->name;
echo $user->username;
echo $user->email;
```

Also note that if you are seeking to get the users ACL's it actually returns as an array. You can see the full object properties and examples here: http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object